# Apache airflow task group execution

Tags: python, graph, airflow

I have several groups of tasks that need to be done one at a time
(when the first task of the group is executed the whole group must be completed (all the tasks of that group must be executed) before moving on to the next group).
If a task within a group fails, then the whole group fails and you can move on to the next group. I wanted to know how I can implement this solution.
Also, as an extra, if a task fails how can I restart it X times until it either runs successfully or fails. Thank you

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBc67.jpg)

in the picture the following order is TG1BOD1 -> TG2BOD1 -> TG1BOD2 -> etc, while the desired one is TG1BOD1 -> TG1BOD2 -> TG1BOD3 -> TG2BOD1 -> etc

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/35URLC2U here there is the code